# Angular material dialog closeOnNavigation source code

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to figure out how angular material solved the problem of preventing backward navigation on open dialogs. By specifying

```
closeOnNavigation: false
```

the dialog will not close and the browser will not navigate backwards if user clicks back button. Searching through the library for "closeOnNavigation" doesn't really lead me to any answers on how this feature is implemented. Any suggestions or does anyone know how they are doing this?

Comment: This flag has no impact on the router's behavior. It simply closes the dialog if a route is changed, or leaves it active.

Comment: @cgTag Aha! I was seeing the blocking navigation behavior because the base component has a function to "block" backward navigation. Leaving dialog open with the flag plus that function caused the behavior. Thanks!